# python: add one element to an existing dictionary from list loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I need to export data from one database into another database. The dataobject needs to be mapped to a dictionary.

each row needs to be saved twice with different values from a list foobar=['foo','bar'].

```
foobar=['foo','bar']
data = []
for q in queryset:
    row = {"id": q.id,
           "created_at": q.created_at}
    for f in foobar:
        row['index'] = f
        data.append(row)
bulksave(data)
```

this doesn't give the desired result:

```
 print data
 [{'id': 1, 'created_at': '2017-01-01', 'index': 'bar'},
  {'id': 2, 'created_at': '2017-01-02', 'index': 'bar'}]
```

Where the desired output would have 'foo' and 'bar' as the index. 
How do I get this to work?
Taking a different approach would be to loop differently:

```
for f in foobar:
    for q in queryset
```

this works, but takes twice the time because each element in the queryset will be evaluated twice.

Comment: You mean you want: [{'id': 1, 'created_at': '2017-01-01', 'index': 'foo'},
  {'id': 2, 'created_at': '2017-01-02', 'index': 'bar'}]?

Comment: @dgg32 correct.

Comment: Are you sure about that `print data`? It should have 4 items, but confusingly its only two unique items with each repeated in the list.

Comment: That "print data" part is his "desired" output.

Comment: @dgg32 - I'm not sure about that either. If queryset has two entries, `data` should have 4 unique entries.

Comment: Please clarify, what indices do you want if your len(foobar) < len(queryset)?

Comment: the print data is the actual output.
desired output is:

`[{'id': 1, 'created_at': '2017-01-01', 'index': 'foo'}, {'id': 2, 'created_at': '2017-01-02', 'index': 'bar'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inner loop. You keep updating the same `dict` and re-adding it to `data`. `data` ends up with multiple references to the same `dict` and the `dict` has been updated to the last value in `foobar`.

Just copy before adding. Also, a note on good question writing... you want a runnable example when possible. Here I mock `queryset` so the thing runs.

```
class Mock:
    def __init__(self, id, created_at):
        self.id = id
        self.created_at = created_at

queryset = [Mock(1, '2017-01-01'), Mock(2, '2017-01-02')]

foobar=['foo','bar']
data = []
for q in queryset:
    row = {"id": q.id,
           "created_at": q.created_at}
    for f in foobar:
        row['index'] = f
        data.append(row.copy())
bulksave(data)
```

**UPDATE**

If you really want to confuse the next person to look at your code, collapse it all into

```
import itertools

class Mock:
    def __init__(self, id, created_at):
        self.id = id
        self.created_at = created_at

queryset = [Mock(1, '2017-01-01'), Mock(2, '2017-01-02')]

foobar=['foo','bar']

bulkupdate(list(dict(zip(('id', 'created_at', 'index'), (q.id, q.created_at, index)))
    for q, index in itertools.product(queryset, foobar)))
```

(`dgg32`'s now-deleted post got me thinking...)

Comment: thnx for the help and the pointers. first question ever... never too old to learn :)

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be the SLC Tom Sanders?